# Combining multiple columns and replacing with the mean of them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, mean

I have pandas datframe like this.

```
    a1      a2      b1      b2    
0    1       2       2       5    
1    3       4       5       4           
2    6       7       8       3         
3    7       7       7       1
```

I want to take mean of a1 and a2 , b1 and b2 and replace it with a and b. Tje result should be the following:

```
      a          b             
0    1.5        3.5              
1    3.5        4.5        
2    6.5        5.5        
3    7          4
```

Comment: I think you should clarify your question a bit with examples of what you have tried so far, and what output you are expecting. See [how to ask a question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by first character of column names and aggregate [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html):

```
print (df.columns.str[0])
Index(['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], dtype='object')

df = df.groupby([df.columns.str[0]], axis=1).mean()
print (df)
     a    b
0  1.5  3.5
1  3.5  4.5
2  6.5  5.5
3  7.0  4.0
```

Another solution for creating `Series` for `groupby` is [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) by regex:

```
print (df.columns.str.extract("([a-zA-Z])", expand=False))
Index(['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], dtype='object')

df = df.groupby([df.columns.str.extract("([a-zA-Z])", expand=False)], axis=1).mean()
print (df)
     a    b
0  1.5  3.5
1  3.5  4.5
2  6.5  5.5
3  7.0  4.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('pd_sample1.csv')

df['a'] = (df['a1']+df['a2'])/2
df['b'] = (df['b1']+df['b2'])/2

df = df.drop(['a1','a2','b1','b2'],axis=1)

print df
```